# How to shorten these duplicate JavaScript code into a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I had ten rows which each rows contain 4 column, now I want to get the value which I had import using localStorage. I find a way to put all these value independently but the code is all the repeat one. These will cause to redundancy of code. I wonder if there are a way to shorten the code using loop?

Here is my code

```
 var res = {};
    $(function(){
     $('#subbtn').click(function() {
      console.log($('#tab').find('tr'))
      $('tr').each(function(){
          var tmp = [];
          var cl ;
          $(this).find('select').each(function(){
            cl = $(this).attr('class');
            //console.log(cl);
            tmp.push($(this).val());
          })

          res[cl] = tmp
      })
        console.log(res);
       localStorage.setItem("testingvalue",JSON.stringify(res));
       document.getElementById("results__display").innerHTML = (localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));
     })

    })
    $( document ).ready(function(){
   var res = {};
   try { 
    console.log('existed');
      res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));

   //alert(res.r1[2]);
   document.getElementsByClassName("r1")[0].selectedIndex=res.r1[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r1")[1].selectedIndex=res.r1[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r1")[2].selectedIndex=res.r1[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r1")[3].selectedIndex=res.r1[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r2")[0].selectedIndex=res.r2[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r2")[1].selectedIndex=res.r2[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r2")[2].selectedIndex=res.r2[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r2")[3].selectedIndex=res.r2[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r3")[0].selectedIndex=res.r3[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r3")[1].selectedIndex=res.r3[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r3")[2].selectedIndex=res.r3[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r3")[3].selectedIndex=res.r3[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r4")[0].selectedIndex=res.r4[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r4")[1].selectedIndex=res.r4[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r4")[2].selectedIndex=res.r4[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r4")[3].selectedIndex=res.r4[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r5")[0].selectedIndex=res.r5[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r5")[1].selectedIndex=res.r5[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r5")[2].selectedIndex=res.r5[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r5")[3].selectedIndex=res.r5[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r6")[0].selectedIndex=res.r6[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r6")[1].selectedIndex=res.r6[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r6")[2].selectedIndex=res.r6[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r6")[3].selectedIndex=res.r6[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r7")[0].selectedIndex=res.r7[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r7")[1].selectedIndex=res.r7[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r7")[2].selectedIndex=res.r7[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r7")[3].selectedIndex=res.r7[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r8")[0].selectedIndex=res.r8[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r8")[1].selectedIndex=res.r8[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r8")[2].selectedIndex=res.r8[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r8")[3].selectedIndex=res.r8[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r9")[0].selectedIndex=res.r9[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r9")[1].selectedIndex=res.r9[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r9")[2].selectedIndex=res.r9[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r9")[3].selectedIndex=res.r9[3];

   document.getElementsByClassName("r10")[0].selectedIndex=res.r10[0];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r10")[1].selectedIndex=res.r10[1];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r10")[2].selectedIndex=res.r10[2];
   document.getElementsByClassName("r10")[3].selectedIndex=res.r10[3];

    } 

    catch (error){
       console.log(error.message);
   }


});
```

Comment: Use the fors, Loop

Comment: I don't know how to get the length of `getElementsByClassName ` and the length **inside** `getElementsByClassName `. I means I had 10 row, and each row had 4 column. How do I get the column size so that I could use the for looop.

Comment: You can set them just like you've extracted them. Looping through all the rows and then all the `select` elements on those rows. In the `select` elements loop you could do something like this `$(this).val(res[cl][$(this).index()])`

Comment: @Titus I was more understanding JavaScript than Jquery. Anyway thanks ya! I know they actually the same, but it just hard for me to understand Jquery :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this repeated line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("r1")[0].selectedIndex=res.r1[0];
```

...a simple first pass improvement would be to just use a nested `for` loop with variables instead of `"r1"` and `0`:

```
for (var r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("r" + r)[i].selectedIndex = res["r" + r][i];
  }
}
```

Notice, though, that this means the `.getElementsByClassName("r" + r)` call happens four time for each value of `r`, which is not very efficient - it would be better to move that into the outer loop:

```
var els;
for (var r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
  els = document.getElementsByClassName("r" + r);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    els[i].selectedIndex = res["r" + r][i];
  }
}
```

In the second version the inner loop could say `i < els.length` rather than `i < 4`, although note that either way you need to be sure you match the number of HTML elements to the number of items in your `res` object.

Comment: I'm just going to edit to remove the repeated calls to `.getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will work regardless the size of your data in storage:

```
res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));
  // Let's start with checking 'res' type.
  // - if it's an Array, get the the length from .length
  // - if it's Object, get the the length from Object.keys().length
  var resLength = Array.isArray(res) ? res.length : typeof res === 'object' ? Object.keys(res).length : 0;
  // loop throw the rows.
  for (var i = 0; i < resLength; i++) {
    // Do the same as above: get type of the row and calculate it length for the loop.
    var rowLength = Array.isArray(res[i]) ? res.length : typeof res[i] === 'object' ? Object.keys(res[i]).length : 0;
    // loop throw the columns on the row.
    for (var j = 0; j < rowLength; j++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('r'+i)[j].selectedIndex=res['r'+i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: At first I was planing to write like this also, but what I write can't get me the correct input. Thanks, but I try your code, it didn't work for me :(

Comment: `res` is an object not an array, the first loop's condition should be `i < Object.keys(res).length` and the second loop's condition `j < res["r" + i].length`

Comment: Ermm, still can't. But the `Object.keys(res[i]).length)` which the **keys** is I can put whatever name I like or is the default one?

Comment: @Beginner `res` is an object you need to call `Object.keys` only on `res` because `res[...]` is an array you can simply do this `res[...].length` no need for `Object.keys(res[...])`.

Comment: @Beginner, I missed `j++` in the inner loop. I think it should work for you now (i've updated code).
Also I refactored the approach how I calculate the length. But checking type of result you get (either Object or Array) and apply different approach to calculate the length. I think you can make it work from here...

Answer (score 0):

You've seem to have the jQuery library loaded. Using jQuery makes this much easier.

Here is an example:

```
var res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));
$("tr select").each(function(){
   $(this).val(res[$(this).attr("class")][$(this).index()]);
});
```

Of course, this will only work if the `select` elements have only one class name and the `res` object contains values for all the `select` elements that are inside `tr` elements. Based on the jQuery code in your question that seems to be the case.

And this is a safer approach

```
Object.keys(res).forEach(function(key){
    res[key].forEach(function(val, index){
        $("tr select." + key).eq(index).val(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: But what if I got 2 name in a class? Because I just get my updated code, and my class name was become two.

Comment: @Beginner You could use the second approach but I guess you will also have to change the jQuery code that creates the object you store in local storage. That code generates the object using `$(this).attr("class")` (all the class names) as a property.