# How do I get getelementbyClassname which the class contain 2 name?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I had a class with two name which is class=test-select r10 and I got ten row of it. For example:

```js
var res = {};

var els;
for (var r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
  els = document.getElementsByClassName("r" + r);
  console.log("Found " + els.length + " for r" + r);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    els[i].selectedIndex = res["r" + r][i];
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="info" id="alertr1">
    <td width="30px">1</td>
    <td width="200px">Likes Authority</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <select class="test-select r1" name="qtyL" onchange="this.size=1" onmouseout="this.size=1" onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="200px">Enthusiastic</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <select class="test-select r1" name="qtyO" onchange="this.size=1" onmouseout="this.size=1" onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get the second name of the class using getelementByClassName??

Comment: You don't have a class with two names, you have elements with two distinct classes. Are you asking how to select elements that have the second class, or how to find out the name of the second class given the first class name? Or...?

Comment: You can hold the class name to a js variable and loop/select which element or child(s) you want to work with.

Comment: Are you asking how to select elements that have the second class - Yes, that's the question. Because I just got my updated code, and there is 2 name on same class. I have no idea what to do. @nnnnnn

Comment: @Beginner maybe, use `document.queryAllBySelector('.test-select .r' + r)` ?

Comment: @ankhzet — Definitely not, that's a descendant combinator … and not what the method name is called.

Comment: @Beginner — `getElementsByClassName` will select all elements that are members of a class, no matter what other classes they are members of. Are you asking how to select *only* elements that are members of both classes?

Comment: @ankhzet It won't work :(

Comment: @Beginner, as I see, both `select`s are using `test-select r1` class declaration. Is that intentional, or should it be `test-select r1` and `test-select r2` respectfully?

Comment: Ermmm, what I ask is like previously my code is  `class="r1" ` only, but now, my code was updated by my college with got two name inside, which is `class="test-select r1"` then `els = document.getElementsByClassName("r" + r);` is not work anymore.

Comment: @Beginner — Adding an extra classname will not break that code. See http://jsbin.com/qofuzopohi/1/edit?html,js,console for a [mcve]

Comment: huh, I mistyped `querySelectorAll()`... lol xD

Comment: Because previously is totally find, but after the class had the two name, my function won't work anymore. I had no idea what wrong with which part

Comment: I'm getting more and more curios about how this code were considered _working previously_ in the first place, as `select`s in provided code differs only by `name` attribute and are populated from json by the same 'r1' json data member value, while they obviously not meant to be like that...

Comment: [How to shorten these duplicate JavaScript code into a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060820/how-to-shorten-these-duplicate-javascript-code-into-a-loop/44060962?noredirect=1#comment75147114_44060962) this is my previous post, it just work fine, the solution provided by him also fine.

Comment: @Beginner — "my function won't work anymore" — It works fine right up until you try to look at r2 which doesn't exist. (I edited the code in the question to turn it into a live demo, that meant fixing a couple of HTML errors and stripping out some JS that is irrelevent to the section you were asking about but which was banned on stackoverflow).

Comment: @Quentin I know where's my problem is. I'm sorry for doing something wrong on this post. Btw, thanks for your reminder and suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I assume you have some inaccuracies in the code:

- You **must** distinct `select`s respective data in `json` by key, you **can't** assume the order in which data is places in json will always correspond to order of elements in yours UI:

  ```
  res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));

  // res now should be in form of
  // res = {
  //   r1: {
  //     qtyL: 2,
  //     qtyO: 3,
  //   },
  //   r2: {
  //      ...
  //   },
  //   ...
  // };
  ```
- You **should not** hardcode any magic numbers into your code, especially if it's about json data structure:

  ```
  var thunks = Object.keys(res).filter(function (name) {
    return name.match(/^r(\d+)$/);
  });
  console.log('found stat thunks:', thunks.join(', '));

  for (var r = 0; r < thunks.length; r++) {
    var thunk = thunks[r];
    var stats = res[thunk];
    var els = document.querySelectorAll("." + thunk);
    console.log('supplied stats for "' + thunk + '" thunk:', JSON.stringify(stats));
    console.log('found "<select>" elements:', els.length);
    ...
  ```
- You, probably, **should not** assume, that your elements in UI will be named exactly like keys in persisted data objects:

  ```
  // some ui-data bridge
  function findSelectsByThunkName(name) {
      if (name.match(/^r\d+$/)) { // stats thunk
          return document.querySelectorAll("." + name);
      } elseif (...) {
         ...
      }

     return [];
  }

  ...

  var thunks = Object.keys(res).filter(function (name) {
    return name.match(/^r(\d+)$/);
  });
  console.log('found stat thunks:', thunks.join(', '));

  for (var r = 0; r < thunks.length; r++) {
    var thunk = thunks[r];
    var stats = res[thunk];
    var els = findSelectsByThunkName(thunk);
    ...
  ```

Working snippet:

```js
// jQuery has 'shortcut' for '$(document).ready(function () { ... });'
// just use '$(function () { ... });' for simplicity's sake
$(function(){
  var res = null;

  try { 
    // assuming 'testingvalue' contains something like '{"r1":{"qtyL": 2,"qtyO": 3,...},"r2":{...},"something":[...],"and_other":1212,..}'
    res = {
      "r1": {
        "qtyL": 2,
        "qtyO": 3,
      },
      "r2": {
      },
      "something": [],
      "and_other":1212,
    }
    
    //res = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));

    var thunks = 
      // get all keys from 'res' object (will get something like ["r1", "r2", "something", "and_other", ...])
      Object.keys(res)
      // and filter them to get only those...
      .filter(function (name) {
        return (
          name.match(
            // that starts (^ symbol) 
            // with "r" character
            // and then have any digit (\d sequence),
            // probably, even more than one (+ symbol)
            // and then ends ($ symbol)
            /^r(\d+)$/
            // this is called "regular expression"
            // you can read more about regexp's on supplied link [1]
          )
        );
      });
      
    // thunks variable now holds the list of "res" object keys, that are corresponding to "^r\d+$" pattern, like ["r1", "r2"]
    
    // as 'array' variables in javascript are in fact objects, they support some convenient methods for array elements manipulation (like mentioned '.filter()' method) etc
    
    // '.join()' is a method of 'array' objects, that concatenates stringified elements of the array, gluing them with provided glue-string, so ["r1", "r2", "r3"] becomes "r1, r2, r3" in this case
    console.log('found stat thunks:', thunks.join(', '));

    // and also 'array' objects have '.length' property that contains current array length
    // we can use it to iterate over all actual elements
    // of array, instead of hard-coding expected array length, which is somewhat ureliable
    for (var r = 0; r < thunks.length; r++) {
      var thunk = thunks[r]; // take key from list (remember, that array element indices are starting from 0)
      var stats = res[thunk]; // now we can access a stats list from 'res' object by picked key
      
      // now we can get the list of 'select' nodes on our page by their selectors
      // ".class-name" in selector below actually means
      // find all elements on page ('document'), that have "class-name" class ("class-name" is specified in their "class" atribute)
      // mentioned "class-name" should only "occur at least once" in 'class' attribute, strict match isn't required, so ".r1" selector will match both <select class="r1"> and <select class="some-other-class r1 and-other and-another"> the same
      // more you can read on the provided link [2]
      var els = document.querySelectorAll("." + thunk);
      
      // btw, beware that '.querySelectorAll()' returns 'NodeList' object, not the 'Array'. It also have '.length' property (like regular arrays) and it's elements can be accessed via bracket-index array access syntax ('els[index]'), but it doesn't have the same convenience mathods, as regular array objects (so, you can't, for example, filter it with 'els.filter()')

      // print data to developer console for debugging
console.log('supplied stats for "' + thunk + '" thunk:', JSON.stringify(stats));
      console.log('found "<select>" elements:', els.length);
      
      // iterate over found 'select' elements
      for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var select = els[i];
        
        // '.getAttribute(attributeName)' returns value of any attribute of html node,
        // for example, for html, supplied in the example, it will return "qtyL" and "qtyO" as "name" attributes for provided 'select' html nodes 
        var name = select.getAttribute("name");
        
        // we can use that "name" as key to access stat indexes from "res" object without relying, that stats in that object are listed and persisted in the same order, in which we are placing our 'select' elements in the page html code, and in which they were fetched and returned by '.querySelectorAll()' method.
        select.selectedIndex = +stats[name];
      }
    }
  } catch (error){
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="info" id="alertr1">
    <td width="30px">1</td>
    <td width="200px">Likes Authority</td>
    <td width="75px;">
        <select class="test-select r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;" onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length" onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1" name="qtyL">
            <option value="0">-</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="200px">Enthusiastic</td>
    <td width="75px;">
        <select class="test-select r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;" onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length" onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1" name="qtyO">
            <option value="0">-</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Useful links:

1. [Doc on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
2. [Doc on Css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)

Comment: Your statement was really useful to me.Thanks and I will study it with my best effort although your code look complicated to me :)

Comment: @Beginner, you're welcome. I can add line-by-line explanation to code if You want. Well, the only part i think You considered complicated may be this `Object.keys(res).filter()`? The rest is almost identical to yours, minus `console.log()` statements...

Comment: Yes, what does the filter mean? :O